# Android: Can I put text data in a 'textView' of another app

Tags: android, service, android-edittext, focus

I have a service that shows an always-on-top [clickable floating button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) on screen irrespective of the context. (User can switch apps and the floating button will always show)(already implemented)

I want to implement such that, whenever user clicks on an `EditText`, **in ANY app**, and click the floating button, it should put some text in that `EditText`.

First I want to know if this is possible atleast? If yes, How!

Let me know if the above para is not enough to make sense what I meant.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you've to elaborate your question clearly. What app you mean. .how do you show FAB from service. .etc

Comment: @cgr as shown here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you do not have rights to do so. But there is a way of doing which is by creating an input service. [InputMethodService | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is create a service that works as an input service, say a custom keyboard. 
You need to take permission `android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD` to do so.